# Subprocess.Popen returning BlockingIOError

Tags: python, subprocess

I am working on a project that involves calling the curl command repeatedly. But on between the 14th and 16th time, subprocess throws this error at me:

BlockingIOError: [Errno 35] Resource temporarily unavailable

The code snippet in question looks like this:

```
counts = []
for i in tqdm.tqdm(range(20)):
    t1 = time.time()
    count = 0
    while time.time() - t1 < 1:
        subprocess.Popen(f'curl -s {site_download} > /dev/null', shell=True)
        count += 1
    counts.append(count)
```

And the result looks like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/markwilson/PycharmProjects/SpeedTest/main.py", line 25, in <module>
    print(measure_download())
  File "/Users/markwilson/PycharmProjects/SpeedTest/main.py", line 21, in measure_download
    subprocess.Popen(f'curl -s {site_download} > /dev/null', shell=True)
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 951, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 1754, in _execute_child
    self.pid = _posixsubprocess.fork_exec(
BlockingIOError: [Errno 35] Resource temporarily unavailable
```

Comment: It is not a python error, take a look at: https://linuxhint.com/resolve-bash-resource-temporarily-unavailable/